# What is a frob?

Tags: oop, tornado

An Intro to Tornado book mentions a "frob object" and search engines are not being terribly yielding, so I hope this is a worthwhile question.

I'm seeing a lot of references to Flicker frobs and [read](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frob) that:

> #### Etymology
>
> It was adopted by the community of computer programmers which grew out of the MIT Tech Model Railroad Club in the 1950s, and allegedly among the oldest existing words in hacker jargon.
>
> #### Noun
>
> **frob** (*plural* frobs)
>
> 1. (*jargon, MIT*) Any small device or object (usually hand-sized) which can be manipulated.
>
>    > Hand me that **frob** there, will you?

So in relation to application and web development, is a "frob object" just any small object that can be manipulated? For example:

```
class SomeFrob(object):
    holder = "something mutable"

frob = new SomeFrob

frob.holder = "mutated"
```

Comment: The lack of references and search results for you should indicate that it's not a common term. Try searching for it with a Tornado context, as it might be more common there.

Comment: I think it's just a made up nonsense word like "Foo" and "Bar".

Comment: It seems to be used in the sense of a meta variable (like foo or bar).

Comment: My understanding is that it has to do with mutation in some way, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/meet-safe-and-unsafe.html as a reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, they are just using the word `Frob` as a substitute or placeholder for a more specific name.  The reason is that the name of the method or class isn't important, the concepts contained within are.

This is the same as calling a class `Foo` or `Bar`.   Now, as to *why* they use `Frob` instead of the extremely common name of `Foo` is beyond me.

The only reference to `Frob` in the context of Tornado I can find is in a book titled [Introduction to Tornado](http://books.google.com/books?id=B-krWzb6KMQC&pg=PA10&dq=tornado%20frob&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vERSVIiuJMqAygTX2YCYBA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tornado%20frob&f=false).  So I wouldn't worry about it too much.  The author likely just wanted to be a bit different.

Comment: Yes. Not to worry. But any word invented by MIT nerds in the 1950's I think I want in my vocabulary.

Comment: In my experience, "frob" is used as a noun, like "widget" is often used by non-computer people. "Foo" and "bar" are akin to variables.